# Updating underline-slider position on resize

Tags: javascript

I have an underline slider for my navigation links that get the specific width and position based on the clicked element, `<li>`, using the getBoundingClientRect(). This works as expected, but on resizing the browser window I would like to update the underline-slider's position.

As it is right now I'm only grabbing the width and position of the first `<li>`. What I need and want to do is to target the specific `<li>` that currently has the underline-slider and update its width and position on resizing so the slider follows along during resize with the right `<li>` element.

Any tip how I could grab the currently active `<li>`??

This is the codepen where I have the example in where I only grab the first `<li>` everytime on resize: 
https://codepen.io/Shenden/pen/PELbOM

the script looks like this:

```
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown > li');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');


function handleEnter() {
// from current li
 const dropCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  //get the current li's width and height
 //apply coords of li's to the slider-div elem
 slider.style.setProperty('opacity', '1');
 slider.style.setProperty('width', `${dropCoords.width}px`);
 slider.style.setProperty('transform', `translate(${dropCoords.left}px)`);

}

//for each li-elem clicked trigger handleEvent function
lists.forEach(listLink => listLink.addEventListener('click', handleEnter));

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  const elem = document.querySelector('.dropdown > li').getBoundingClientRect();

  slider.style.setProperty('transform', `translate(${elem.left}px)`);
  slider.style.setProperty('width', `${elem.width}px`);
});
```

Comment: can you post your own code so that we can help you ?

Comment: @NejiSoltani i think he wrote the code in that codepen

Comment: @TimothyGroote that's the working example

Comment: @NejiSoltani it is the link to codepen, I also pasted it in here. The pen is working, but with me only grabbing the first li-element. I want to grab the currently active one when I resize the browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of which item should be active by flagging it with a class like this :

```
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown > li');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');


function handleEnter() {
 //remove active item indicator class if it is present
 document.querySelector(".activeItem").classList.remove("activeItem");
 //add the active item indicator class to the current item
 this.classList.add("activeItem");

 //perform the move code for the underline
 const dropCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();
 //get the current li's width and height
 //apply coords of li's to the slider-div elem
 slider.style.setProperty('opacity', '1');
 slider.style.setProperty('width', `${dropCoords.width}px`);
 slider.style.setProperty('transform', `translate(${dropCoords.left}px)`);

}

//for each li-elem clicked trigger handleEvent function
lists.forEach(listLink => listLink.addEventListener('click', handleEnter));

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  //select the correct item using the activeItem indicator class
  const elem = document.querySelector('.dropdown > li.activeItem').getBoundingClientRect();

  slider.style.setProperty('transform', `translate(${elem.left}px)`);
  slider.style.setProperty('width', `${elem.width}px`);
});
```

CodePen fork : [right here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyLrPq)

Comment: i was just doing the same until you won the race :)

Comment: @NejiSoltani that happens sometimes. it does mean your solution was good though :)

Comment: As simple as that, great stuff. Never crossed my mind, I blame it on the flu :) Thanks @TimothyGroote